# complie shared library ,but other linker doesn't work

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a shared library developed from `SDL` so i am using linkers flags

```
-lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm
```

but when testing it doesn't link

Makefile :

```
CC  := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm
CTFLAGS := -Wall -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm -L/home/mz37/programming/MZSDL
LDFLAGS = -shared

RM = rm -f   # rm command
TARGET_LIB = libSGK.so  # target lib

SRCS = src/mzsdl.c src/container.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: ${TARGET_LIB}

test-container.out: ${TARGET_LIB} test/container-test.c
    $(CC) $(CTFLAGS) -o $@ test/container-test.c -lSGK

$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^

$(SRCS:.c=.d):%.d:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< >$@

include $(SRCS:.c=.d)

clean:
    -${RM} ${TARGET_LIB} ${OBJS} $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

and the result when test my file `test-container.out`:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm -MM src/container.c >src/container.d
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm -MM src/mzsdl.c >src/mzsdl.d
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm   -c -o src/mzsdl.o src/mzsdl.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm   -c -o src/container.o src/container.c
gcc -shared -o libSGK.so src/mzsdl.o src/container.o
gcc -Wall    -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lm -L/home/mz37/programming/MZSDL -o test-container.out  test/container-test.c -lSGK
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccm0XYCK.o: in function `main':
container-test.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: container-test.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: container-test.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: container-test.c:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
/usr/bin/ld: container-test.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRGBSurface'
.....
.....
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mz37/programming/MZSDL/libSGK.so: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mz37/programming/MZSDL/libSGK.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mz37/programming/MZSDL/libSGK.so: undefined reference to `TTF_RenderText_Blended'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: test-container.out] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place `-o test-container.out test/container-test.c` just after `gcc -Wall` to be  **before** the `-l...`, the order is relevant and the linker need to know whose symbols are missing, it cannot guess in advance what is required by (at least) *container-test*

place `-lm` at the end, you are sure the lib math does not need the other libs but may be the other libs needs the lib math.

Note you only need `-lm` when you do the link, not when you just compile (option `-c`)